# Upload vCard (.vcf) file to IIS7 Site

Tags: iis-7, mime-types, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to upload a vcard file to a site i've built with ASP.NET. It's hosted on an IIS7 server.

I keep running into the "content type not allowed" error when i try to upload the file. I have write permission to the directory, I've already added the MIME type for vcards and restarted the IIS server, however it still refuses to take it.

I'm using DevExpress UploadControl and i've removed any validation from it so i am fairly certain the control is not restricting the file upload.

Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Maybe* your component just allow some content types by default and new ones must be granted access manually.

Can you to debug your server side code, to see if your page code executes and to spot exactly what component are throwing up that error?

It's an HTTP error or a .net exception?